# GNU emacs on ssh and auto-save

Tags: ssh, emacs, remote-access

I encountered problems of dropped ssh session, which is quite frustrating.
I first open up a terminal, and using ssh to login to a remote machine running Ubuntu Linux 13.04.
Then in that ssh session, I often need to use GNU emacs (23.4.1) to edit files, read emails, etc.
The problem is that while editing, emacs tries to do auto-save the buffer contents.  Often, while doing auto-save, my emacs session got stuck somehow, becomes unresponsive, and eventually it kills the ssh connection.  I am wondering what is really wrong here. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you have.
Thanks a lot!
BVP

Answer (score 0):

So your remote emacs gets stuck saving?

Perhaps try running gnu screen or tmux on the remote server before launching emacs. That way if you lose connection, your emacs session will still be accessible when you log on again.